# Laravel Mix and Monaco Editor

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix, monaco-editor

Let's start by saying I'm not very proficient with Webpack, so, it might be a trivial question.

I'm trying to use Monaco in a Laravel project through the `monaco-editor-webpack-plugin`. Since the plugin needs modifications to `webpack.config.js` and Laravel uses `webpack.mix.js`, by fiddling around I managed to come up with the following configuration:

```js
/* eslint-disable import/no-extraneous-dependencies */

const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');

const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
                languages: ['css', 'html', 'javascript', 'json', 'scss', 'typescript'],
            }),
        ],
    });
```

Now, everything works fine, files get compiled and the editor works as expected. The Issue I'm having is that the editor's compiled files are being generated in the `/public` directory. E.g: `/public/editor.worker.js`, `/public/0.js`, etc.

I would really like to avoid this and have those files compiled in `/public/js/vendor/monaco` instead. I tried to change the `output` config to `/public/js/vendor/monaco` but it compiles everything (css, fonts, etc) into that directory.

Is there a way to say "Hey, I want those Monaco files here while leaving everything else as is?".

Comment: What about changing the `publicPath` mentioned in https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor-webpack-plugin ?

Comment: @apokryfos it changes the path from which the files will be loaded by the editor but they're still compiled in the root path.

Comment: you can use extract to move it to vendor.js - **Note:** if you want more information you can check here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#vendor-extraction

Comment: Have you tried .extract()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in laravel-mix function `copy` to help. What you can do is, leave the output as is and just copy that output file into the desired directory once processed. Here is how you can do that.

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/scss/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig({
        plugins: [
            new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
                languages: ['css', 'html', 'javascript', 'json', 'scss', 'typescript'],
            }),
        ],
    })
    .copy('SOURCE_PATH', 'DESTINATION_PATH');
```

Define all the files you want to copy, using the chained `copy` function call. Alternatively, There is another laravel-mix method `copyDirectory(fromDir, toDir)` to copy the entire directory.

For more advanced usage, You can perform post-processing on assets manually from the mix `Promise` resolution as given,

```js
mix.then(function () {
  //Perform post-processing on generated assets
}) //Will be triggered each time Webpack finishes building.
```

Here, You'll have a free hand to copy/delete/rename assets using [fs module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html),

Alternatively, the vendor extraction may help. You can get the `Monaco` editor to the `vendor.js` file using `extract()` by passing the library name in the array. It will output the `vendor.js` file into the public directory and then after `copy()` function may help you to copy that file.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I did in the beginning, and then deleted the original files, but this just feels clunky. I'll wait a bit to see if anyone else wants to jump in.

Comment: @Ben Clunky is the only way sometimes :), However, the method `copy` comes in a mix so there is a meaning of having that method. I also believe that's clunky but it's the only workaround.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, if that's the only way then that's the only way. Monaco generates 80+ .js files with "semi-random" names.

Comment: how about the `extract ` and then `copy`

Comment: I ended up leaving it as is, sometimes you just have to live with it. Thanks!